# Apply a batch script to all the csv file of my directory

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, cmd

I have a script that allow me to extract a specific columns from a csv file.
My aim subject is to apply my script to all csv files of my directory.

```
@echo off>fourcol.csv

setlocal 

for /f "tokens=1-22* delims=," %%1 in (ManyColumns.csv) do (

    echo %%4,%%5,%%6>>fourcol.csv
)

type fourcol.csv
```

1. Apply the script to all the csv file in my directory
2. Remove duplicates

> FileA.csv ...FileZ.csv
>
> server1,Dell,1.0.1,server1,Dell,28/06/2016,...
>
> server2,Hp,1.0.2,server2,Hp,29/06/2016,...
>
> server3,Dell,1.2.1,server3,Dell,30/06/2016,...
>
> server4,Hp,1.3.1,server4,Hp,27/06/2016,...
>
> server3,Dell,1.2.1,server3,Dell,30/06/2016,...
>
> server4,Hp,1.3.1,server4,Hp,27/06/2016,...

My CSV files have the same header and the same data.

Output after applying the script (without duplicates):

> server1,Dell,1.0.1
>
> server2,Hp,1.0.2
>
> server3,Dell,1.2.1
>
> server4,Hp,1.3.1

Comment: What do you mean by remove duplicates?

Comment: The csv files may contain duplicate row.

Comment: So you will be happy with just "Apply the script to all the csv file in my directory"?

Comment: I found out how to remove duplicates from a csv file. 
@ECHO OFF 
SETLOCAL 
FOR /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a=" 
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (fileA.csv) DO SET $%%a=Y 
(FOR /F "delims=$=" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO ECHO %%a)>resultfile.txt 
GOTO :EOF

Comment: Do you want one `result.csv` at the end (ie a merge) or lots of of individual extract files? If the answer to that is yes, then do you want to remove the duplicates from the individual csv files first and then do the extract/merge? Or the other way around? **Note that the result could be different.** (one strips dupes from individual files, the other strips dupes across all files). Please [edit] and clarify your requirements.

Comment: Yes if I apply the script to all the csv file, then I'll concanet all the results in one file and I'll apply my script to remove duplicates.

Comment: My csv files have all the same data, and the same header, at the end I want to remove duplicates

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I apply the script to all the csv files in my directory?

A couple of small changes should do it:

1. Don't use numbers as `for` loop variables. They are reserved for command line parameters.
2. Use `dir /b *.csv` to get the list of files to process.
3. Start from token 1 **not** token 4 to extract the first three columns.
4. Use the first `for` loop to process each file, and a second (nested) `for` loop to process the lines within the file.

Note:

- `delims=,` may not do what you want (if there are values in the file that contain commas `,`).

Try the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal
rem remove output file if it already exists
if exist fourcol.csv del fourcol.csv
rem loop through the csv files
for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`dir /b *.csv`) do (
  rem loop through the lines in each file
  for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%b in (%%a) do (
    echo %%b,%%c,%%d>>fourcol.csv
    )
  )
rem add code here to strip duplicates
endlocal
```

test.csv:

```
server1,Dell,1.0.1,server1,Dell,28/06/2016,...
server2,Hp,1.0.2,server2,Hp,29/06/2016,...
server3,Dell,1.2.1,server3,Dell,30/06/2016,...
server4,Hp,1.3.1,server4,Hp,27/06/2016,...
server3,Dell,1.2.1,server3,Dell,30/06/2016,...
server4,Hp,1.3.1,server4,Hp,27/06/2016,...
```

fourcol.csv:

```
server1,Dell,1.0.1
server2,Hp,1.0.2
server3,Dell,1.2.1
server4,Hp,1.3.1
server3,Dell,1.2.1
server4,Hp,1.3.1
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.

Comment: Unfortunately, the batch file returns a result csv file that contain commas ,,

Comment: @user3029217 Please edit the question and provide a small sample csv file, and also the intended output from applying the script. Note: it is always better if you provide sample before and after data with a scripting question. Then we can test our answers ... ;)

Comment: I have updated the question. I tested the script again and this time I didn't had any output

Comment: @user3029217 Please see updated answer. Running `test.cmd` in the same directory as `test.csv` produces `fourcol.csv` with the expected output. You can modify `test.cmd` as appropriate to strip the duplicates.

Comment: I don't what your original batch file was doing but it appeared to start from column 4 **not** column 1 (which would never have worked). Note that now you have provided proper test data we can test the answer and make sure it is correct ... please make sure you do that next time.